# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars(error)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
next_layer = [array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])]
```

I am trying to apply `math.tanh` function over it but it gives me the above error. How to fix it.

I am doing sort of lyk this.
It under a for loop and I am doing next `layer[i] = math.tanh(next_layer[i])`

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong. `math.tanh` only works on 1-element arrays that can be converted to scalars. You need to use `np.tanh` on an array.

Comment: Also, you do realize that `next_layer` is a list with only one element, right? The element is the numpy array.